# How to make Superclass Method returns instance of SubClass

Tags: java, subclass

I have a class called `Test` and a class called `SubTest` who extends `Text`, I would like to have a method in the `Test` class who will returns the instance of `SubTest` when called, I would like to do :

```
SubTest test = new SubTest().setTest("Hello!").setOtherTest("Hi!");
```

The `setTest()` and `setOtherTest()` methods should be in the `Test` class.

But when I do :

```
public Test setTest(String test) { return this; }
```

It only returns the instance of `Test` so I have to cast `Test` to `SubTest`, but I don't want to.

**Is it possible ? If yes, how ?**

*Thanks, MinusKube.*

Comment: Will your `Test` class be `abstract`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having a method return its owner (`this`) to be able to 'chain' multiple method calls is called *fluent API*. You can solve your problem by using generics, although the resulting code might be somehow less readable though:

```
public class Person<T extends Person<T>> {
    public T setName(String name) {
        // do anything
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class Student extends Person<Student> {
    public Student setStudentId(String id) {
        // do anything
        return this;
    }
}

public class Teacher extends Person<Teacher> {
    public Teacher setParkingLotId(int id) {
        // do anything
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, you do not need any casts:

```
Student s = new Student().setName("Jessy").setStudentId("1234");
Teacher t = new Teacher().setName("Walter").setParkingLotId(17);
```

See also: [Using Generics To Build Fluent API's In Java](http://www.unquietcode.com/blog/2011/programming/using-generics-to-build-fluent-apis-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have those methods return a `SubTest`, because Java's return types are covariant.

You must override those methods so that you can return `this`, a `SubTest`, in `SubTest`, e.g.:

```
@Override
public SubTest setTest(String message) {
    super.setTest(message);  // same functionality
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to override all methods for all classes ?

Comment: Yes, or else they will return `this` typed as `Test`.  At least the overridings are trivial.