# Method in superclass that returns instance of subclass

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

This question is the equivalent of Java's [How to make Superclass Method returns instance of SubClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820288/how-to-make-superclass-method-returns-instance-of-subclass)

Suppose this class hierarchy:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A makeCopyOfObject();
};
class B: public A
{
    public:
        void doSomethingB();
};
class C: public A
{
    public:
        void doSomethingC();
};
```

I'd like to use it this way:

```
B().makeCopyOfObject().doSomethingB();
C().makeCopyOfObject().doSomethingC();
```

But of course I can't, because the `makeCopyOfObject` function returns an instance of `A`, not an instance of a subclass.

I surely could write two versions of the function in the two subclasses, but the code would be the same, except for the return type, because all fields to be copied and modified are in the base class. So, is there an alternative?

Comment: you can declare the copy method virtual, and then override it in the derived classes, so you get the expected behaviour.

Comment: why would you want to do that ? 
That violates Liskov substition principle.

Comment: @Melkon No, this doesn't work if an object needs to be returned.

Comment: @alain: You are right, I missed that he doesn't give back a pointer, but copy methods does, so he should change this if he want to use this design.

Comment: Why is it not desirable to make doSomething (instead of doSomethingB/doSomethingC) a virtual function (perhaps pure virtual in A)? Why is a copy required? In the example context, which could be oversimplified to demonstrate this point...the copy is lost when it falls from scope. I realize there COULD be reasons, but do they apply to the OP's problem? makeCopyOfObject can't return B or C by value.

Comment: Is there a vital need for this to be modeled with inheritance? Could B or C contain an A object instead of inherit from an A object? Or do you really need the polymorphic behavior (use B and C functionality through a pointer to an A)?

Comment: If you have a class hierarchy without virtual methods, you are doing it wrong; and if you have a class hierarchy and pass instances by value, you are doing it wrong. Note C++ is not Java. Don't try to copy your Java intuition to C++ literally. If you want to emulate Java, you pass and return most things by pointer/reference, and you want most of your methods virtual.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you try to achieve with that and it is probably not an answer (see comments), but what you can do is a template (in detail a [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)).

```
template<typename CRTP>
class A {
public:
    CRTP& makeCopyOfObject() {
        return static_cast<CRTP&>(*this);
    }
};

class B: public A<B> {
public:
    void doSomethingB();
};

class C: public A<C> {
public:
    void doSomethingC();
};
```

And use it as you wanted:

```
b.makeCopyOfObject().doSomethingB();
c.makeCopyOfObject().doSomethingC();
```

See running example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a3abadb31fe152f).

---

**Sidenote:**
Because of laziness, even the function is called `makeCopyOfObject` it does **not** create a copy, but returns a reference to the object. To do a copy you have to implement copy constructors and return a copy (search for clone pattern).

Comment: **−1** First because a reference is not a copy. Second because the class template `A` is not a common base class as in the question. I.e. in two different ways this does **not answer** the question, at all.

Comment: It's not the answer as `A<B> != A<C>`

Comment: `B` & `C` no longer have the same base-class

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see any practical use case for this, but it's easy to do with a non-member function template:

```
template< class Type >
auto copy_of( Type const& o )
    -> Type
{ return o; }
```

Then you can write

```
copy_of( B() ).doSomething();
```

to your hearts' content, instead of just writing

```
B().doSomething();
```

Enjoy.

---

For the academic issue of covariant methods, there is a lot to be said. You might check out answers to how to implement a `clone` method. Essentially, this is not supported by C++ except for type system support for reference or pointer result, so one must do it "manually", and the three common approaches are (1) fully manual implementation in each class, (2) using a macro that expands to necessary code in each class, and (3) a middle-man class that forwards arguments to base class constructors. With C++03 the third way was about the same order of difficulty as leveraging dominance in a virtual inheritance hierarchy, so with C++03 that was also an option to be mentioned. But it's just not in the right ballpark of practicality with C++11 and later, (1), (2) and (3) it is.

Answer (score 0):

First, beware of [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Second, if you want to make a copy of an object, may I suggest
the copy-constructor:

```
B b1{};
B b2{b1}.doSomethingB();
```

or even:

```
B{ B{} }.doSomethingB();
```

Also, if you want to preserve polymorphic behaviour, always
handle polymorphic classes via [smart-pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or references.

Note that C++ has [value-semantics](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/), while Java has reference-semantics, so design-patterns that are good for Java are not necessarily good for C++.